# refreshing a sprite in cocos2d android

Tags: java, android, refresh, sprite, cocos2d-android

How do I refresh a sprite without recreating it? like my health meter is getting overlapped by freshly created sprites how do I keep the health meter on top of everything without having to destroy and recreate it? I'm using the cocos2d library for android.

Comment: change the z order, or put it on an extra layer that's above all other nodes (using z order or simply add that layer last)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cocos2D uses the z value of children in a layer to order them, just set the z value of the health meter to a value greater than all the other sprites your using.

Answer (score 0):

Just use setTag() method to set the Tag for the sprites. For your app, give a higher tag value for the sprite health meter than other sprites, automatically the sprites with lower tag value will be displayed behind the health meter.